# Insert a variable in a text file

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to using sed -i command to insert a string variable in the 1st line of a text file.
This command work : `sed -i '1st header' file.txt` 
But when i pass a variable this doesn't work. 
example :

```
var=$(cat <<-END
    This is line one.
    This is line two.
    This is line three.
END
)

sed -i '1i $var' file.txt # doesn't work
sed -i ’1i $var’ file.txt # doesn't work
```

Any help with this problem

Thank you

Comment: Why didn't you try `"1i $var"`? And how did you get those other strange thingies that look like reverse backticks anyway...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let's define your variable a simpler way:

```
$ var="This is line one.
This is line two.
This is line three."
```

Since sed is not good at working with variables, let's use awk.  This will place your variable at the beginning of a file:

```
awk -v x="$var" 'NR==1{print x} 1' file.txt
```

#### How it works

- `-v x="$var"`

  This defines an awk variable `x` to have the value of shell variable `$var`.
- `NR==1{print x}`

  At the first line, this tells awk to insert the value of variable `x`.
- `1`

  This is awk's shorthand for print-the-line.

#### Example

Let's define your variable:

```
$ var="This is line one.
> This is line two.
> This is line three."
```

Let's work on this test file:

```
$ cat File
1
2
```

This is what the awk command produces:

```
$ awk -v x="$var" 'NR==1{print x} 1' File
This is line one.
This is line two.
This is line three.
1
2
```

#### Changing a file in-place

To change `file.txt` in place using a recent GNU awk:

```
awk -i inplace -v x="$var" 'NR==1{print x} 1' file.txt
```

On macOS, BSD or older GNU/Linux, use:

```
awk -v x="$var" 'NR==1{print x} 1' file.txt >tmp && mv tmp file.txt
```

Comment: doesn't work, no thing happen when tested in a script

Comment: @Sami It worked fine for me.  I just tested it again and added the results to the answer as an example.  If it works differently for you, please provide details.

Comment: Thanks John. but the change inplace does'nt work.

Comment: _"change inplace does'nt work"_  What does that mean?  Which of the two change-in-place commands were you using?  Which OS are you on?  In what way did it not work?  Was there an error message?  What did it say?

Comment: This command : awk -i inplace -v x="$var" 'NR==1{print x} 1' file.txt

Comment: awk -i inplace -v x="$var" 'NR==1{print x} 1' file.txt
Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...
Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] [--] 'program' file ...
POSIX options:          GNU long options:
        -f progfile             --file=progfile
        -F fs                   --field-separator=fs
        -v var=val              --assign=var=val
        -m[fr] val
        -O                      --optimize
        -W compat               --compat

Comment: @Sami What OS are you on?  What version does `awk --version` show?

Comment: @Sami Also, if it turns out that your version of awk is too old to support `-i inplace`, then try the macOS BSD version.

Comment: awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.7
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2009 Free Software Foundation.
is it old ?

Comment: @Sami Yes, that is old.  3.1.7 was [released nearly a decade ago](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.awk/lBxgDQlh17Y).  Try the command in the macOS/BSD version.  That should work with old GNU awk as well.

Comment: i don't have macOS/BSD, i am with unbuntu 14

Comment: @Sami On an old Ubuntu, please try `awk -v x="$var" 'NR==1{print x} 1' file.txt >tmp && mv tmp file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Using `printf`...

```
$ var="This is line one.
This is line two.
This is line three.
"
```

Use `cat -` to read from `stdin` and then print into a new file. Move it to the original file if you want to modify it.

```
$ printf "$var" | cat - file > newfile && mv newfile file;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best job for `sed`. What about a simple `cat` ?

```
cat - file.txt <<EOF > newfile.txt
This is line one.
This is line two.
This is line three.
EOF

# you can add mv, if you really want the original file gone
mv newfile.txt file.txt
```

---

And for the original problem - `sed` does not like newlines and spaces in it's 'program', you need to quote and escape the line breaks:

```
# this works
sed $'1i "abc\\\ncde"' file.txt

# this does not, executes the `c` command from the second line
sed $'1i "abc\ncde"' file.txt
```